# How to randomly remove 100 blocks from a text file

Tags: python, linux, awk

Suppose I have a huge text file like below:

```
19990231  
blabla   
sssssssssssss  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh  
ggggggggggggggg                  

20090812  
blbclg  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh  
ggggggggggggggg  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

20010221  
fgghgg  
sssssssssssss  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  
ggggggggggggggg

<etc>
```

How can I randomly remove 100 blocks that start with numeric characters and end with a blank line? Eg:

```
20090812  
blbclg  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh  
ggggggggggggggg  
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  
<blank line>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is not clear, please wrap your sample input and sample outputs into code tags `{}` button and do let us know  then.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You cannot remove material from within a file; you have to read it in, and write back selected portions to a new file. First write a program that simply copies; then add logic that skips certain parts.

Comment: Why do you have both the tags `python` and `awk`?

Comment: Do you just want to delete those 100 blocks from the file, or do you want to do something with them, eg print them?

Comment: so from the above blocks, I would like to remove randomly a let's saying one block (the one from the middle ( 20090812
blbclg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
ggggggggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh) and the output should look like:                                          19990231
blabla
sssssssssssss
hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
ggggggggggggggg                                                                 
20010221
fgghgg
sssssssssssss
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
ggggggggggggggg

Comment: I just want to delete them from the file. My file has about 700 blocks, so I would like to delete by random 100 blocks

Comment: Ok. This is easy to do if you can read the whole file into memory. But if you don't want to do that you need to make two passes over the file. On the 1st pass you count the blocks, on the second pass you copy the wanted blocks to a new file. Of course, you can do it in one pass if you can supply the number of blocks as an input parameter.

Comment: If you define the problem as deleting, say, 3 blocks out of 6 instead of 100 out of 700, and make each block, say, 3 lines instead of 5, then you can post a [mcve] with concise, testable, sample input and expected output and so make your problem clearer and give us something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww just downvoted all answers again so I'm upvoting them all again.

Answer (score 3):

This is not that difficult. The trick is to define the records first and this can be done with the record separator :

> **`RS`:** The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a `<newline>` by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. *If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a `<newline>` plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a `<newline>` shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.*

So the number of records is given by :

```
$ NR=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}END{print NR}' <file>)
```

You can then use `shuf` to get a hundred random numbers between 1 and `NR`:

```
$ shuf -i 1-$NR -n 100
```

This command you feed again in `awk` to select the records:

```
$  awk -v n=100 '(NR==n){RS="";ORS="\n\n"}       # reset the RS for reading <file>
                 (NR==FNR){print $1; a[$1];next} # load 100 numbers in memory
                 !(FNR in a) { print }           # print records
                ' <(shuf -i 1-$NR -n 100) <file>
```

We can also do this in one go using the [Knuth shuffle](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#AWK) and doing a double pass of the file

```
awk -v n=100 '
   # Create n random numbers between 1 and m
   function shuffle(m,n,    b, i, j, t) {
       for (i = m; i > 0; i--) b[i] = i
       for (i = m; i > 1; i--) {
          # j = random integer from 1 to i
          j = int(i * rand()) + 1
          # swap b[i], b[j]
          t = b[i]; b[i] = b[j]; b[j] = t
       }
       for (i = n; i > 0; i--) a[b[i]]
   }
   BEGIN{RS=""; srand()}
   (NR==FNR) {next}
   (FNR==1)  {shuffle(NR-1,n) }
   !(FNR in a) { print }' <file> <file>
```

Comment: someone down voted all answers again.  I'm reverting it back.

Comment: Not "someone", our resident repeat offender @jww. I've upvoted all answers again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` and `shuf` to delete 4 blocks out of 6 blocks where each block is 3 lines long:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
NR==FNR { next }
FNR==1 {
    cmd = sprintf("shuf -i 1-%d -n %d", NR-FNR, numToDel)
    oRS=RS; RS="\n"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        badNrs[line]
    }
    RS=oRS
    close(cmd)
}
!(FNR in badNrs)

$ awk -v numToDel=4 -f tst.awk file file
1
2
3

10
11
12
```

Just change `numToDel=4` to `numToDel=100` for your real input.

The input file used to test against above was generated by:

```
$ seq 18 | awk '1; !(NR%3){print ""}' > file
```

which produced:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3

4
5
6

7
8
9

10
11
12

13
14
15

16
17
18
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution without shuffle

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v n=100 '
        BEGIN  {srand()} 
        NR==FNR{next} 
        FNR==1 {r[0]; 
                while(length(r)<=n) r[int(rand()*NR)]} 
       !(FNR in r)' file{,}
```

double pass algorithm, first round is to count number of records, create a random list of index numbers up to required value, print the records not in the list.  Note that if the deleted number is closer to number of records, the performance will degrade (probability of getting a new number will be low).  For your case of 100 out of 600 will not be a problem.  In the alternative case, it would be easier to pick the to be printed records instead of deleted records.

Since `shuf` is very fast I don't think this will buy you performance gains but perhaps simpler this way.

Comment: @EdMorton No, it will stop when `length(r)==n+1`.